# Convert C# code to VBscript

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have next 'while' statement which I should re-write on VB:

```
    while (--number >= 0)
    {
        result = (char)('A' + number % lettersNumbers) + result;
        number /= lettersNumbers;
    }
```

I've tried something like this:

```
While number >= 0
    number = number - 1
    result = Chr(Chr("A") + number Mod lettersNumbers) & result
    number = number / lettersNumbers
WEnd
```

But unfortunately it doesn't works. I am getting next error:

> Type mismatch: '[string: "A"]'
>   So how to correct this code to make it work on VBscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
While number >= 0
    number = number - 1
    result = Chr(Asc("A") + number Mod lettersNumbers) & result
    number = number / lettersNumbers
WEnd
```

You need to get the character code of "A":

Comment: Answered the same answer later and still gets the upvotes. I don't understand the mechanics of this site :-D

Comment: Code dumps just do better. No need for any effort to read what you have explained... @RomanoZumbé

Comment: @PatrickHofman Oh, thats kind of sad. Just solve the problem and don't understand the cause of it ... I'll stay with explaining what causes the problem :-)

Comment: And now the answering user (which was registered today) is deleted. Seems odd to me

Answer (score 5):

You need to get the character code of "A":

```
While number >= 0
    number = number - 1
    result = Chr(Asc("A") + number Mod lettersNumbers) & result
    number = number / lettersNumbers
WEnd
```

The function `Asc` returns the Ascii code for a given letter. in your original you use a charcater (char) in a calculation. C# implicitly converts char to int.

Comment: Actually, `Asc` returns the ANSI character code value. The ANSI character set is the one of many possible character sets that is configured for the thread at the time the code runs. (The thread initially inherits from the process, which initially inherits from the user, which initially inherits from the operating system installation.)